# Is it safe to use java built-in `serialization` to passing objects to JMS queue?

Tags: java, serialization, jms, gson

We use some jms servers in project. When passing objects, we have two options:

1. Mark the message class as `implements Serializable`, then pass it directly. (the message class is just a simple java bean)
2. Use `Gson` to serialize them to json, then deserialize in consumer side

And think more:

1. We just passing them in internal queues now, which means they are all run in a single JVM
2. We may turn to use external queues in the future
3. The message may have nested fields in the future

I prefer the first option since it's easy, and have better performance than the second one.

But my colleages prefer the second one, they said they hear there are some issues(but they don't know exactly) with the java built-in serialization, they may have problems some day.

Which option shall I choose? Is there any problem with the built-in serializtion provided by Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you use persistent JMS messages, you should use a text format as Gson or XML, because messages will survive an application update.

When using serialized java objects you may run into problems after application updates, because some objects won't be deserializable anymore. Then XML will also have the advantage of having a clearly defined schema.

When you use non persistent JMS messages and all messages are supposed to get lost when the application is shut down, then serialised java objects might be an option. But I would use them as a last resort, because handling this format can really be a big problem.